# How can I make the following table be displayed in this way instead of just horizontally?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database named Books, which has a Table named BookInfo, which contains the following data:

[image]

If I execute the following query, the data is displayed like this:

[image]

However, I want a query that displays the data like this instead (Without the BookID):

[image]

Could someone please tell me what do I have to specify in my query so it can show me the data that way?.

I searched on the internet about different ways I could solve this, but so far I haven´t been able to find anything. I couldn´t try anything because I genuinely don´t have any idea how I am supposed to show the data that way.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`. For example:

```
select pages1, chapters1, price1 from bookinfo where bookid = 1
union all
select pages2, chapters2, price2 from bookinfo where bookid = 1
union all
select pages3, chapters3, price3 from bookinfo where bookid = 1
```